# Root password change method

Tags: linux

I have try change root password and non of article mentions this command to change root password `sudo passwd`

But how does that change root password with your you specifically stating root user

Answer (score 1):

The `passwd` command will change the password for the current user. Optionally if you're root you can provide a username and have it change their password (for example, `passwd smith`). See `man passwd` for the details.

The `sudo` command is an administrative tool that takes the rest of its command line and runs that as another user. By  default it runs commands as the root user. (In a managed environment your systems administrator would be the only person allowed to use this tool. But when you're running your own system you have the rights to it, too.)  See `man sudo` for the details.

Putting these together as `sudo passwd`, the `sudo` command runs `passwd` in the context of the root user, so you get to change root's password.

Answer (score 0):

Skip sudo.  If you know the root password, just su to root and run the passwd command.  For example:

```
$ su -
Password:  (enter the root password here)
# passwd
(follow the prompts)
```